Can suppressing sexual feelings at an early age lead a person to become asexual?
If a parent discovers their teenage boy watching 18+ videos on digital devices,
they could take decisive action to mitigate the situation. This includes confiscating
or restricting access to digital devices, implementing strict usage guidelines, and
possibly setting up parental controls to prevent future occurrences.
Can suppressing sexual feelings at a young age potentially impact a person's sexual orientation or lead to asexuality?

No.
While there aren't that many studies I have found focused on asexuality specifically we have seen for practically every other sexual orientation that it can't be controlled by such things as parental rules, restrictions, or attempts to suppress desires; so it's logical to assume the same is true for asexuality.  Asexuality is something that one is mostly born with not something likely to be developed or affected by environmental factors (short of messing with the teen's hormones, but obviously you probably shouldn't do that without REALLY good reasons).  As such you can't force it on someone, nor can you stop someone who is asexual from being asexual.  You would have just as much luck attempting either of those actions as you would trying to turn a gay child straight.  There is a reason most developed nations outlaw conversion therapy; it's been shown that it doesn't work and just does harm to the child.
So no there is no realistic risk of turning a teen asexual or changing their sexual orientation no matter what you do.  There is a risk of ruining your relationship, parental authority, and dialogue with a child though.
Instead my advice is speak to the teen, explain you don't like their viewing porn and would like them to stop, but accept they likely won't and don't make demands that they stop that will almost certainly be ignored.  Instead focus on explaining why adults don't want teens to watch porn.  It sets unrealistic expectations of sexuality, relationships, and what the human body should look like.  It's not real and not what you should expect out of relationships etc.  Treat porn as at best entertainment, but not a model for what real life is like.

The first part answers the question, but the second part quite unhelpfully states there is nothing to be done against a teen watching porn. OP can limit opportunities, by limiting the time the kid has available for being alone in their room with a screen. Make sure he has sufficient other interests and activities (physical, social, intellectual) to limit the time spent watching porn (or doomscrolling on tiktok).

If you try to influence the behaviour of your child then up to some level there will be no permanent effect (neither damage nor benefit nor other change). So suppressing sexual feelings to some “normal” level will have no long term effect.
If the parents do this to a criminal degree they can cause permanent damage. That’s why in civilised countries for example any attempt at “treatment” of gayness will get a medical doctor struck off and a non-doctor will be a criminal.
Since what the parents do will either have no effect other than making the kid unhappy, or cause severe psychological damage, any parent should stay far away from it.
